# Cruise Control Force a Build through Command Line Call

Tags: build-automation

Is there a way to force a build in cruise control from command line or from another build running on a remote machine ? Kindly help ....

Answer (score 4):

The CruiseControl wiki has [instructions](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/RunningCruiseControlFromUnixInit) to do just that. A short summary is available on this [blog](http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2009/06/cruisecontrol-hack-kicking-off-builds.html).

Comment: Great. :) You should mark the answer as accepted, though, because otherwise people will still read the question thinking it hasn't been answered yet.